# Cant tidy up login page after bootstrap install MVC 4

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a standard login page on mvc 4 which is functioning fine but my html knowledge is very weak and I need a quick answer to tidying up the form after I installed twitter bootstrap, the username and password labels are stuck on the same line within the form, can someone please recommend a quick fix to tidying up my code, Thanks

```html
@model MvcApplication2.Models.login_details

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}
<br /><br /><br />
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.username, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.username, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div> 
                
                <div class="form-group">
                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                       
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.password, new { @class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy :)
Just change the LabelFor's class from col-md-2 to col-md-3 then add another item, text-left.

So your labels should look like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label text-left" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label text-left" })
```

Then goto Site.css (~/Content/site.css) and add the following to the bottom:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label.text-left{
    text-align: left;
}
```

[image: done!]

I would recomend though that you learn HTML/JS/Bootstrap as if your making websites ever professionally you almost always will have to be competent with basic HTML/JS/Bootstrap(sometimes)

Comment: Alternativly you could just change the inputs to have col-md-12 (instead of col-md-3 on the label) as this would be more semantically correct as you want them to take up the whole row, but I chose to use the labels as that way your only changing one place rather than two.

The reason why it jumps down is col-md-3 + col-md-10 == 13, the page is made up of (usually) 12 col-md- so it has to drop the col-md-10 down to meet this requirement